# org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1 The attribute "xlink:href" of the element <use> is required

Tags: xml, apache, svg, element, batik

We generate SVG Document it looks fine, but when we try to work with it :

```
UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgentAdapter();
BridgeContext ctx = new BridgeContext(userAgent);
ctx.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.DYNAMIC);
GVTBuilder builder = new GVTBuilder();
builder.build(ctx, svgDocument);
```

ER: Caused by: org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1

```
The attribute "xlink:href" of the element <use> is required 
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGUseElementBridge.buildCompositeGraphicsNode(SVGUseElementBridge.java:120) [%HOME%/lib/batik-all_new.jar:1.8pre+r1435044] 
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGUseElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGUseElementBridge.java:98) [%HOME%/lib/batik-all_new.jar:1.8pre+r1435044] 
at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:213) [%HOME%/lib/batik-all_new.jar:1.8pre+r1435044] 
at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171) [%HOME%/lib/batik-all_new.jar:1.8pre+r1435044] 
at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219) [%HOME%/lib/batik-all_new.jar:1.8pre+r1435044] 
...
...
```

BUT if we recreate svgDocument from String or file:

e.g.

```
SVGDocument svg = factory.createSVGDocument("svg", new ByteArrayInputStream(svgString.getBytes()));
```

or

```
SVGDocument svg = factory.createSVGDocument("svg", new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\file.xml")));
```

There are no mistake. Could you help?

Thanks.

P.S. **use element does exist but we have some weird bug at runtime**

```
SVGUseElement svg = (SVGUseElement)svgElement.getOwnerDocument()
    .createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
svg.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#" + deviceObjectParameters.pictureURL.hashCode());
<use xlink:actuate="onLoad" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" transform="translate(0.0, 0.0) rotate(0, 0, 0) scale(1.0, 1.0)" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#1232024040"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use setAttribute to set an attribute in the xlink namespace, it will only create attributes in the null namespace. What you need instead is setAttributeNS for xlink:href attributes.

```
svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#" + deviceObjectParameters.pictureURL.hashCode());
```

Comment: I've did it. But new err:  null:-1
Cannot find the referenced element:
"#1232024040"
specified on the element <use> - may be a problem of 'id'

Comment: Probably, using hashCode seems wrong, you need some other element's id.

Comment: We had the same issue, caused by a wrong namespace uri. In our xsl template we had the namespace<br/>
`xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink"`

<br/>Changing it to<br/>
`xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`
<br/>
resolved the problem